# Python Get excel column size

Tags: python, excel

Is there any way to get excel's original column width or height using python?

I found many answers like adjust column width... calculating len of letters to figure out the width of the column but len of letters may not actually mean the width of original size of width right?

I need to create a separate excel file from a original excel file with exact shape (width,height size)

if there aren't any functions can anyone suggest smart way to go about doing this..?

please help

Answer (score 0):

You can import openpyxl and get the dimensions you need :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet = book['Sheet1']
print(sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width)
print(sheet.row_dimensions[1].height)
```

you can also set the dimensions, e.g:

```
sheet.row_dimensions[1].height = 25
```